# BackgroundWorker with Webclient downloadstring

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, webclient, downloadstring

So basically I want to retrieve the content of a .txt file on the internet and write it into a a label. However though, while it does this Windows Forms freezes.

So I thought of putting it into a BackgroundWorker. There is also a progress bar which should be filled during the progress. My code looks like this:

```
private void RetrieveTxt(string currentversion)
    {
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        label1.Text = wc.DownloadString("http://example.org/version.txt");
    }

void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateProgress.Visible = false;
    }
```

However though, it doesn't work; the label never gets updated and the progress bar stays empty.

Any help is appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: you can use async/await if you are on .Net 4.5

Comment: And if you are using BackgroundWorker you need to do :
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: And... remember to not modify any UI object inside of the `DoWork` code or you will receive a nice exception. For that purpose you have the `ProgressChanged`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using C# 5.0 you can do the following:

```
label1.Text = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://example.org/version.txt");
```

It's just that easy.

If you're not, then you can leverage the async support of `WebClient`; you don't need to use a BackgroundWorker:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, data) =>
{
    label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = data.Result));
};
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.org/version.txt"));
```

As for why your code doesn't work:

1. You never actually started the worker.  You never called `worker.RunWorkerAsync();`
2. You're accessing a UI control from a background task, so it will just break when you try to access the label from the `DoWork` handler.  You would need to set the result to be the string that the `WebClient` returns and then set the label in the completed handler.

Comment: thank you very much for the very detailed answer! learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a delegate because the background thread can't operate on UI controls:

```
private delegate void InvokeUpdateText(String theText);
private void UpdateText(String theText)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        try { Invoke(new InvokeUpdateText(UpdateText), theText); }
        catch { }
        return;
    }
    label1.Text = theText;
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    UpdateText("http://example.org/version.txt");
}
```

Comment: The whole *point* of using a BGW is so that you *don't* need to do this.  You can just set the result and then modify the UI in the completed handler, which runs in the UI thread.  Also, the empty catch all block is a *terrible* thing to do.  Don't do that.

Comment: First, it's a mistake to believe that the background worker somehow saves you from improperly accessing a UI element.  Second, there's nothing to glean from specific error-handling in an Invoke.  Catch it if you'd like, but what would you do with it?  Best to use this catch-all as a means of last resort...the UI should be consuming them anyhow, making it a moot point.

Comment: The fact that you don't know what you'd do with the exception is *precisely why you shouldn't catch it*.  You should only catch an exception when you *do* know what to do with it.  I never said BGW saves you from all mistakes, I said it's purpose exists to simplify synchronizing a long running task with the UI.  You're using a BGW and not leveraging any of the functionality it has for this purpose.  If you aren't going to use it to do it's job, why use it at all?